# Latex, Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a code that goes something like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Topics in Claims Reserving}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{section2}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

But the table of content does not starts at the page of table of contents, rather it starts after 1 page . See the picture attached :

---

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: You ask for that behavior, because you create a new chapter and afterwards `\tableofcontents` creates a new one for you. Solution: Alter the command that generates the chapter name for the toc.

Comment: @TeXnician I am new at using LaTeX, can you please elaborate your answer? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: since `\tableofcontents` automatically creates the list including an appropriately formatted heading (in the case of `report`, `\chapter*`), you should just omit (or comment out, if you like that better) the `\chapter*{Table of Contents}` line, and instead `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks a lot :D Worked Just Fine. thanks again. ^_^ I am grateful to this community of stackexchange.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{tocbibind}` in order to prevent the `\addcontentsline` for the ToC itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `\tableofcontents` automatically creates the list including an
appropriately formatted heading (in the case of `report`, `\chapter*`),
you should just omit (or comment out, if you like that better) the
`\chapter*{Table of Contents}` line, and instead

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
```

this is the simplest and most direct method of changing the toc for one of the basic
document classes, if you don't need to make any other changes.